# Evaluating this integral for any integer $n>1$ : $\int \limits _0^ {\infty} \ln^n\frac{|1-x|}{|1+x|}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

How do I evaluate this integral for any integer $n>1$

$$\int \limits _0^ {\infty} \ln^n\frac{|1-x|}{|1+x|}\,dx$$

**Note**: for $n=1$ just we use integral by part and the integral will be divergent .My problem what about $n >1$

Thank you for any kind of help

Comment: Did you try to find some recurrence?

Comment: it is very hard to use reccurence ,sorry i can't get a recurrent formula

Comment: What does the exponent $n$ mean? Is it multiplicative power, or composition?

Comment: it's not composition ,it's multipilicative

Answer (score 4):

Consider that the integral may be split up as follows;

$$\int_0^1 dx \log^n{\left (\frac{1-x}{1+x} \right )} + \int_1^{\infty} dx \log^n{\left (\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right )}$$

The first integral may be evaluated for any positive integer $n$ by subbing $e^{-u}=(1-x)/(1+x)$; the result is that the integral is equal to

$$2 (-1)^n \int_0^{\infty} du \frac{e^{-u}}{(1+e^{-u})^2} u^n$$

We may then expand the denominator in a Taylor series and reverse the order of integration and summation to get

$$2 (-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (k+1) \int_0^{\infty} du \, u^n \, e^{-(k+1) u} $$

Evaluating the integral, we get

$$2 (-1)^n n! \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^n} = 2 (-1)^n n! \left (1-\frac1{2^{n-1}} \right ) \zeta(n)$$

This holds even when $n=1$ (by taking a limit or evaluating the sum directly).

The second integral may be made to look like the first integral by subbing $x \mapsto 1/x$; the result is:

$$\int_0^1 dx \log^n{\left (\frac{1-x}{1+x} \right )} \frac1{x^2} $$

Using the same substitution, we get

$$2 (-1)^n \int_0^{\infty} du \frac{e^{-u}}{(1-e^{-u})^2} u^n  $$

Doing the same thing as in the first integral, we get that the second integral is

$$2 (-1)^n n! \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^n} = 2 (-1)^n n!  \zeta(n)$$

Note that $n \gt 1$ here necessarily.  Thus, we may finally write down the result:

> $$ \int_0^{\infty} dx \log^n{\left |\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right |} = 4 (-1)^n n! \left (1-\frac1{2^{n}} \right ) \zeta(n)$$

**ADDENDUM**

When $n=2 m$, the expression simplifies to

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \log^{2 m}{\left |\frac{x-1}{x+1} \right |} = 2 (-1)^{m + 1} (2^{2 m} - 1) B_{2 m} \pi^{2 m}$$

where $B_{2 m}$ is a Bernoulli number.

Comment: now it seems good ,thanks